# Navigating and sorting XML within xsl:variable using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

The XML within the 'formslist' variable is created using apply-templates.  This snippet is from a 2.0 stylesheet.

```
<xsl:variable name="formlist">
    <forms>
     <FORM form_name="form1" print_seq="1200"/>
     <FORM form_name="form2" print_seq="1500"/>
     <FORM form_name="form3" print_seq="9000"/>
     <FORM form_name="form4" print_seq="5500"/>
    </forms>
</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="$formslist/*">
     <xsl:sort select="FORM/@print_seq"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

The XML outputs ok but it is not sorted by print_seq

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed discussion of the problems in the provided XSLT code and for a short and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:variable name="formlist">    
>     <forms>    
>      <FORM form_name="form1" print_seq="1200"/>    
>      <FORM form_name="form2" print_seq="1500"/>    
>      <FORM form_name="form3" print_seq="9000"/>    
>      <FORM form_name="form4" print_seq="5500"/>    
>     </forms>    
> </xsl:variable>    
>
>     <xsl:for-each select="$formslist/*">    
>      <xsl:sort select="FORM/@print_seq"/>    
>      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>    
>    </xsl:for-each>
> ```

**The problems with this code**:

1. **The `formlist` variable has no specified type and by default its type is `document-node()`.** This means that `$formlist/*` select the single top element `forms` and sorting a single element results in exactly this element (unchanged). This problem would have been avoided if the type of the variable had been specified as `as="element()"`.
2. **Even if the above problem had been solved, the specified sort key `FORM/@print_seq` is incorrect** -- a `FORM` element doesn't have a `FORM` child. The correct sort key would be just: `@print_seq` .
3. **Even if the first two problems above didn't exist, the sort would still be incorrect, because the sort key type is treated as string and not as a number**. The correct `<xsl:sort>` instruction needs to have `data-type="number"` specified or the sort key itself should have been specified as `xs:integer(@print_seq)`

**Solution**:

**Simply use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>   

 <xsl:variable name="formslist" as="element()">
    <forms>
     <FORM form_name="form1" print_seq="1200"/>
     <FORM form_name="form2" print_seq="1500"/>
     <FORM form_name="form3" print_seq="9000"/>
     <FORM form_name="form4" print_seq="5500"/>
    </forms>
</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="{name($formslist)}">
        <xsl:for-each select="$formslist/*">
         <xsl:sort select="@print_seq" data-type="number"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<forms>
    <FORM form_name="form1" print_seq="1200"/>
    <FORM form_name="form2" print_seq="1500"/>
    <FORM form_name="form4" print_seq="5500"/>
    <FORM form_name="form3" print_seq="9000"/>
</forms>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$formslist/*` selects `forms` element.

You could declare $formlist as:

```
<xsl:variable name="formlist" as="element()"> 
    <forms> 
     <FORM form_name="form1" print_seq="1200"/> 
     <FORM form_name="form2" print_seq="1500"/> 
     <FORM form_name="form3" print_seq="9000"/> 
     <FORM form_name="form4" print_seq="5500"/> 
    </forms> 
</xsl:variable>
```

But you will loose the `forms` element in the copy.

Other solution will be an identity rule with sorting. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="formlist">
        <forms>
            <FORM form_name="form1" print_seq="1200"/>
            <FORM form_name="form2" print_seq="1500"/>
            <FORM form_name="form3" print_seq="9000"/>
            <FORM form_name="form4" print_seq="5500"/>
        </forms>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$formlist" mode="copy"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="copy">
                <xsl:sort select="self::FORM/@print_seq"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<forms>
    <FORM form_name="form1" print_seq="1200"/>
    <FORM form_name="form2" print_seq="1500"/>
    <FORM form_name="form4" print_seq="5500"/>
    <FORM form_name="form3" print_seq="9000"/>
</forms>
```